# PHP rolling dice guessing

Tags: php

Im new to php and i cant get my program to display correctly. If code doesnt working, i dont get a text like Great Job, You're Good! 
I just want to make a simple guessing game, you guess the number and you will see if you guess the right number sure random number.

Here is my code (php.html)

```
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
                 <body>

         <form name = "Dice roller" action="game_check.php" method="post">

           Your guess: <br>

         <input type= "text" name="" size= "1">

       <input type ="submit" name = "submit">

      </form>
     </body>
        </html>
```

Game_check.php

```
    <html>
      <body>
         <?php
        $roll = $_POST['submit']; 
        $dice =  rand(1, 6);

        if ($roll == 1 && $dice == 1) 
       { 
          print "Great Job, You're Good!"; 
       }
       else if ($roll == 1 && $dice /= 1) 
       {
             print "Wrong"; <br >
       }



       if($dice == 1) print "<img src='1.png'>"."<br>";
       if($dice == 2) print "<img src='2.png'>"."<br>";
       if($dice == 3) print "<img src='3.png'>"."<br>";
       if($dice == 4) print "<img src='4.png'>"."<br>";
       if($dice == 5) print "<img src='5.png'>"."<br>";
       if($dice == 6) print "<img src='6.png'>"."<br>";

               else {
                  print "Thanks". "<br>";
            }

            ?>

       <form name= "Back" action= "php.html" method= "post"> 
       <input type="submit" name="back" value ="Play again">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I have an if loop for 6 dice .. 
Thank you

Comment: I give, I win; is that the game?

Comment: *Hm...* `/=` <= wha'dat?

Comment: yeah your if statements make it so you can only win if the roll is 1, even if you guess the roll right. also i dont think `/=` is the operator youre looking for, but i dont know PHP so who knows.

Comment: `action="php.html"` uhm... Perhaps checking out some decent tutorials would be beneficial

Comment: @Noah i think this is corect, the page where the form is stored is called "php.html"

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd guess it's a try for the hand-written not equal (equal with a slash)

Comment: where did you learn about these if loops? They sound amazing

Comment: @PhilippMurry The convention of putting PHP code within a `.html` file is incorrect, and naming the file is one of the first things that happens when building code... I still maintain that OP needs to work from the ground up on PHP basics, particularly considering that he doesn't know how to compare two variables.

Comment: @Noah I was never referring to this 'convention'. I was just saying that the filename `php.html` is not necessarily bad, as it is just used as a name for testing php (as in "in this project I want to try out php for the first time, so lets call that page `php.html`"). he could've used `test.html` as well, but this isn't really an issue at this point (there are others).

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I almost thought it looked like a crack at division. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
else if ($roll == 1 && $dice /= 1)
```

to

```
else if ($roll == 1 && $dice != 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are wrong you just need. You also have a break that you need to move into your `print`.

```
if ($roll == $dice) 
{ 
    print "Great Job, You're Good!"; 
} else {
    print "Wrong<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use the correct syntax. If you want to check if two objects are NOT EQUAL, the operator looks like this:

```
a != b
```